# I have to get the characters in a row after a particular character

Tags: javascript

For example my string is:

```
"Hi @randomperson !! how are you?"
```

and if I have to get all characters starting from the `@` to the space before the exclamation marks.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You can use regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: split using space as a delimiter, check for first character '@' on each token. regex should work great for this.

Comment: Actually the problem is that I don't know how to do that. Could you please help me please. Sorry I am a newbie! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var input = "Hi @randomperson !! how are you?",
    re = /@\S+/g;

console.log(re.exec(input)[0]); // prints "@randomperson"
```

- The forward slashes (`/`) are regex literal delimiters
- `@` matches a single `@` character
- `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace character

That's it.

More information on regex in JavaScript: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html.

Comment: actually, it will print "randomperson"

Comment: @MattBall, what is your goal with the parentheses?

Comment: thnx this worked! i'll accept your answer in a few minutes(its not allowing me to accept it right now :P)

Answer (score 0):

```
myString.match(/\B@\S+/)
```

should do it.  It will either return `null` or an array whose first element is the matched string.

The leading `\B` will stop it from matching in the middle of an email address, so it will not match

```
"randomperson@example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var text = "Hi @randomperson !! how are you?";
var userID = text.match(/@(.*)(?=\s!!)/)[1];
```

Comment: Way overcomplicated regexp, IMO

Comment: @MattBall granted, it could possibly be `/@\w*/` but the OP specified "to the space before the exclamation marks".  I therefore assume that !! is a magic number for the end of the command.

Comment: @Joseph: I think it he just wanted to point out which space in this example... but the OP knows better.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var txt = ((new RegExp("@[\w\s]*")).exec(your_string)[0] || '')
```

This will check your string by using regexp and if no match is found, it results in an empty string.